# Bootstrap glyphicon between two inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap3 griding system. I have two following input fields and I would like to put glyphicon between them. Unfortunately it doesn't work when I allocate entire column for glyphicon itself. Gap between controls are too big.

Could you please help me to add glyphicon between `flyFrom` and `flyTo` input fields. Thanks for any help!

**HTML:**

```
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" id="flyFrom" placeholder="Country, city or airport">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" id="flyTo" placeholder="Country, city or airport">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                            <input type='text' id="depart-date" class="form-control" />
                             <span class="input-group-addon">
                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                             </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                            <input type='text' id="return-date" class="form-control" />
                             <span class="input-group-addon">
                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                             </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class='btn-group'>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">1 Adult<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Adults 12+ years</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Children under 12</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Children under 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button type='button' class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/z4b2bwg6/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I did not understand you question in first place!! My Bad!

In this example the icon should be between the two inputs:

```
<div class="input-group input-large">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="from">
        <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>  </span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="to">
    </div>
```

I hope this will help you.

See also this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0rssd727/1/

Comment: Yes, it's better not to allocate a separate column for the icon, it's better to put two input fields with an icon in one bootstrap column. 

It is a good solution, thanks. :) It works.

Comment: My Pleasure. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal"></i> 
</div>
```

Try this?

Comment: Is the glyphicon working? If not then you might have appended the Bootstrap files incorrectly. If it is could you post a picture of what it looks like on your screen?

Comment: I have only 6 reputation score, need 10 in order to add the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an inline icon in the first input control like this:

```
<div class="input-group ">
     <input type='text' id="return-date" class="form-control input-md" >
         <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
         </span>
```

Comment: Idea is that I want glyphicon between controls not in the first one... :)